# Buenas. Alguien que me pueda explicar o ayudar de como exportar en pdf los registro de cada fila en mysql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Este es el código que me genera la consulta de toda la tabla

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM mitabla";
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));
  $item = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $item = $item+1;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias librerías en **PHP** para generar documentos **pdf**.

Con http://www.fpdf.org/ por ejemplo, sería tan sencillo como el siguiente código:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$x = $y = 10;                    // Inicializamos x e y
$pdf = new FPDF();              // Creamos el objeto pdf
$pdf->AddPage();                // Añadimos la primera página
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);  // Seleccionamos el tipo de fuente
$pdf->SetXY($x,$y);             // Vamos a la posición x=10, y=10

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mitabla";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));
$item = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{

  $pdf->Cell(40,10,$row[1]); // Imprimimos el resultado del primer campo
  $y = $y + 10;              // Bajamos la posición en 10 puntos
  $pdf->SetY($y);            // para escribir la siguiente línea 
  $item = $item+1;
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías darnos algo mas de información para saber con que trabajas, pero yo te recomendaría FPDF, es una librería muy buena, nosotros la utilizamos y en que aprendes a utilizarla (es muy sencillo), generas unos PDF muy buenos.

> Te dejo por aqui el link a su web http://www.fpdf.org/